# MYSQL Create table + Alter table incorrect syntax?

Tags: sql, mysql, foreign-keys, create-table

I'm trying to create a table in Navicat and immediately add a foreign key relation after that. The syntax however seems to be incorrect... Is this even possible?

```
    CREATE TABLE `Bld` (
      `id` int(10) NOT NULL
      PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

    ALTER TABLE `Bld` (
        CONSTRAINT `fk_Bld_Bld_Ref` FOREIGN KEY (`id`) REFERENCES `Bld_Ref` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
    );
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you are missing a comma:

```
CREATE TABLE `Bld` (
  `id` int(10) NOT NULL, -- <- there
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```